# Embedding shiny app in another web app

Tags: shiny

Thank you in advance for reading this.
It has been a while I build shiny app, and recently I started to learn NODEJS.

One questions that I'm struggling with is: How can I use shiny app like a service to other web app.

For example I want to handle everything on a node js app but I have one interactive plot that due to huge data manipulation it is much easier to do that in a R shiny app.

I really appreciate if you could spread some light if you have similar experiences.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the app in an iframe.